# Compare dates from different databases in R

Tags: r

I work with R. I have two databases db1 and db2.

db1 has two fields:  person and Date_A where person is a character variable but Date_A is a date variable. Each person is assigned to one date.
db2 has also two variables, person and Date_B.  some people appear in both databases, while others only appear in Db1.

I need to find a list of people who are found in both databases such that date_A is older than date_B for that person.  What is the best way to do so in R?

Comment: Hi Gunnar, could you please share small examples of `db1` and `db2`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following logical, with `dplyr` functions:

```
df1 <- data.frame(person = c(letters[1:10]), date = sample(1:50,10))


df2 <- data.frame(person = c(letters[6:15]), date = sample(1:50,10))


df3 <- inner_join(df1, df2, by = "person") %>%
  mutate(date = ifelse(date.x < date.y, date.x, NA)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(date) == TRUE) %>%
  select(person, date)
```